# SCons copying program after compilation to parent directory

Tags: c++, build, makefile, scons

I am trying to copy the generated program file to the parent directory after compilation automatically.

I tried this, but this doesn't work.

```
env.Program( "program_name", [ "file1.cc", "file2.cc" ] )
Copy( "../program_name", "program_name" )
```

How can I do this with SCons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A better approach would be to use the target and the Command() builder, like this:

```
prgTarget = env.Program( "program_name", [ "file1.cc", "file2.cc" ] )
Command(target = "../program_name",
        source = prgTarget,
        action = Copy("$TARGET", "$SOURCE"))
```

Or depending on the situation, use the [Install() builder](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.3.4/HTML/scons-user/ch11.html), like this:

```
prgTarget = env.Program( "program_name", [ "file1.cc", "file2.cc" ] )
Install("../program_name", source = prgTarget)
```

Comment: +1 This sounds like a good job for the install builder. Using a command builder sounds like complicating the code. Do you know of any situations a command build would have any advantages?

Comment: @daramarak, the Command() builder is more flexible, as it can be any command, like scripts, etc. The Install() builder is just for "installing" (copying) one or several files/targets.

Comment: I know that the Command builder is flexible, but I was wondering if there were cases a Command builder should be preferred for copying a file instead of the Install builder?

Comment: @daramarak, I cant think of any, which doesnt mean that there arent any :) With Command() you could change the name, with Install() you cant. But you could change the name with InstallAs() instead.